# Is it better to filter content in a subreport or hide it using visibility on the column?

Tags: rdl

I want to hide all stock parts that aren't a specific range of part numbers (ex. 300-0000 through 300-9999). Is it better to create a subreport and filter based on that range of part numbers or create a column set the visibility to only show that range of parts?

I've tried to pull the same fields from a report into the subreport and filter but I don't know how to filter on a range. Typically I would do a contains or startswith but neither of those options are available with RDL reports. I'm open to any and all suggestions. Thank you all.